# Express + login script

Tags: javascript, express, async-await

My login script was working with Postman, but as soon as I attempted to get React.js to post it to the server it started breaking.

The issue is that, when it checks for the user, it is not able to pass back the `return result` For some reason it just does not do anything.

Login route:

```
router.post('/login', async (req,res) => {
    console.error(req.body.password)
    try {
        var check = await checkUser(req.body.email, req.body.password).catch((result) => {
            console.log(result)
        })
    } catch(err){
        console.error(err)
    }
});
```

Check function:

```
async function checkUser(username, password) {
    var username = username;
    var password = password;
    var result;
  
    await Users.findOne({email: username}, async function (err, docs) { 
    // console.error(docs);
    if (err) { 
        console.log(err) 
    } else { 
        const match = await bcrypt.compare(password, docs.password);

        if(match) {
            result = {userid:docs._id, success:"true"}
            //result['userid'] = docs._id;
            //result['success'] = true;
        } else{
            result = {success:"false"}
            // result['success'] = false;
        }     
    }
    // console.error(result);
    return result;  
  })
}
```

Wondering if anyone can see where I am going wrong.

Comment: You're not returning anything as a response i.e. `return res.json({ result })`

Comment: Also, is there a reason you're declaring `username` and `password` as variables when they're already passed as arguments?

Comment: @Daniel_Knights mainly because for some reason. It won’t read res.body.email or in fact res.body in general.

Comment: If you don't return a response the frontend won't receive any data

Comment: Just try `return res.json({ result })` and then console log the full response on the frontend, see what you get.

Answer (score 0):

Dont use `.catch()` if you go with `async / await`. To catching errors you already have `try / catch`

```
router.post('/login', async (req,res) => {
    console.error(req.body.password)
    try {
        var check = await checkUser(req.body.email, req.body.password)
    } catch(err){
        console.error(err)
    }
});
```

Down there similar problem. You use the callback approach with `async / await`. The reason why you doesnt get anything back is that you returning your result to your callback function `...async function()..` if you take a closer look.

However as i said, dont use callback + `async / await`

Remember use either: `async / await` or chaining `.then() .catch()` or use the callback approach but not all together its bad and leads to unessecary bugs.

```
async function checkUser(username, password) {
  var username = username;
  var password = password;
  var result;
  try {
    let user = await Users.findOne({ email: username });
    if (!user) return "no user found";

    const match = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);
    if (match) {
      result = { userid: user._id, success: "true" };
    } else {
      result = { success: "false" };
    }
    return result;
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```